# Помогите расставить знаки препинания: где нужны запятые, а где тире?

Tags: пунктуация

*Мечта советского рабочего выкованный молотом и подрезанный серпом заднеприводный седан первый из классического "семейства" автомобилей Волжского автомобильного завода правильно ВАЗ 2101.*

Comment: Помочь можно тому, кто начал что-то делать. Где хоть одна запятая или тире?

Answer (score 1):

Как замечательно, что Вы не просите аргументировать расстановку знаков, это мы мигом!

*Мечта советского рабочего  - выкованный молотом и подрезанный серпом заднеприводный седан, первый из классического "семейства" автомобилей Волжского автомобильного завода (правильно ВАЗ 2101).*

Тире - между подлежащим и сказуемым; запятая - между однородными членами; скобки - потому что пояснение вне структуры предложения!

---

Дополнение с учетом комментария автора. Ведь не было ни намёка, что внутри предложения могут содержаться вопрос-ответ...

Тире и запятую оставляем без изменений;

после *Волжского автомобильного завода* возможны вопросительный знак, многоточие или сочетание этих знаков.

*Правильно* - непременно новое предложение, и тоже возможны варианты со знаками:

*Правильно: ВАЗ 2101!*

*Правильно, ВАЗ 2101.*

Comment: А если я хочу чтоб словосочетание ВАЗ 2101 было НЕ в скобках, например так: Мечта советского рабочего выкованный молотом и подрезанный серпом заднеприводный седан первый из классического "семейства" автомобилей Волжского автомобильного завода - правильно, ВАЗ 2101. Или так не бывает? :)

Comment: Оля, если это игра в "угадайку", то знаки действительно будут другие: ***Мечта советского рабочего - выкованный молотом и подрезанный серпом заднеприводный седан, первый из классического "семейства" автомобилей Волжского автомобильного завода?.. Правильно: ВАЗ 2101!*** Возможны варианты в зависимости от вкладываемого смысла и интонаций.

Comment: Надо бы в скобках написать "официальное название" вместо "правильного". И скобки на месте, так как одно тире здесь уже есть. А запятая после "правильно" - это уже неправильно, как Вы объясните  такую грамматику?

Comment: Ариша, но ведь автор хочет вопросительного предложения с откликом, нет? Я дополнила по мере разумения ответ.

Answer (score 0):

первый из классического "семейства" автомобилей Волжского автомобильного завода, - правильно, ВАЗ 2101. По-моему, так

Comment: «Нельзя же так увлекаться собой», — пожаловалась на меня пожилая дама, когда в метро мы сцепились зонтиками и я нечаянно протащил её за собой метров пять.  По-моему, у вас та же проблема, — торопитесь, срезая углы.

Answer (score 0):

Мне представляется Ваше предложение в таком виде:
***Мечта советского рабочего — выкованный молотом и подрезанный серпом — заднеприводный седан: первый из классического семейства автомобилей Волжского автомобильного завода, правильно — ВАЗ 2101.***

Или в таком, чуть перестроенном:
***Мечта советского рабочего — выкованный молотом и подрезанный серпом — заднеприводный седан: первый автомобиль из классического семейства Волжского автомобильного завода, правильно — ВАЗ 2101.***

**семе́йство**
3. *перен.* совокупность схожих по каким-либо признакам объектов, продуктов и т. п.
В указанном предложении семейство = группа, кавычки не нужны:

*"Ермак" — семейство автомобилей ГАЗ.

"Тайфун" — семейство бронеавтомобилей повышенной защищённости.

Принципиально новое семейство автомобилей "Вожак" разрабатывается специалистами университета им. Тимирязева.*